# Change Gridview Textbox's visible property true false on DropdownLists's Selected index change event using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am making Gridview's Textbox visible true or false when user changes Dropdownlists selectedIndexchange event for that i have done following code

My .CS File code is as below:

```
protected void gvTaskList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnStatus");
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlStatus");
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtVal");
                if (ddl != null)
                {
                    ddl.Items.Add("Not Started");
                    ddl.Items.Add("In Progress");
                    ddl.Items.Add("Complete");

                    if (hdn != null)
                    {
                        ddl.SelectedValue = hdn.Value;
                    }
                    //ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
                    ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return myFun(" + "'" + txt.ClientID + "'" +");");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.ErrorList("EmpTaskList--RowdataBound", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Note: My combobox and textbox both are in EditTmplate

Javascript code is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFun(txtControl) {

    var v = document.getElementById("<%=" + txtControl + "%>");
    alert(v);
}
```

When i m changing dropdownlist index function is called and alert is showing null.

So can anyone please suggest me what i m doing wrong??

Comment: if `txtControl` is a variable passed to myFun, I don't think you'd need those `("<%="+`. Just try it like `getElementById(txtControl)`.

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012479/how-to-find-dynamic-control-in-java-script-created-using-asp-net and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011975/getting-a-dynamic-textbox-name-using-javascript . You are doing this in rowdatabound are you sure this `(TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtVal");` brings you anyrhing? The controls might not have been rendered, I am not sure but try Page_Init or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want the server-side tags in your `getElementById` call:

```
var v = document.getElementById(txtControl);
```

Comment: What's rendered in the page? Did you try an alert on txtControl?

Comment: OK, we've established that `getElementById` isn't returning anything. How about txtControl? Are you getting the right id passed in?

Comment: btw what is alert supposed to show when you send it a textbox as a parameter Mr.Noonan?

Comment: You are not sending a "textbox", you are sending the ID of the textbox. What is the ID that was sent?